# Creating a constructor in C++ with many arguments that are not known

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm trying to create a class that loads in individual items from a JSON file and then creates the item itself using templates and many different constructors with varying types, what is the best way to do so? I'm trying to see if there's a way in C++ instead of using this switch statement:

```
GameData* GameData::setData(JsonObject& jDat)
{
    std::string itemType = jDat["ItemType"].toString();

    switch(itemType)
    {
        case "Weapon":
            return new weapon(jDat["Name"].toString(), jDat["Description"].toString(),
                jDat["Rarity"].toString(), jDat.contains("Cursed") ? jDat["Cursed"].toBool() : false,
                jDat.contains("Stackable") ? jDat["Stackable"].toBool() : false);

        case "Consumable":
            return new consumable(jDat["Name"].toString(), jDat["Description"].toString(),
                jDat["Rarity"].toString(), jDat["StackMax"].toInt(), jDat["Amount"].toInt(),
                jDat.contains("Cursed") ? jDat["Cursed"].toBool() : false,
                jDat.contains("Stackable") ? jDat["Stackable"].toBool() : false);

//        ......
        
        default:
            return new consumable(jDat["Name"].toString(), jDat["Description"].toString(),
                jDat["Rarity"].toString(), jDat["StackMax"].toInt(), jDat["Amount"].toInt(),
                jDat.contains("Cursed") ? jDat["Cursed"].toBool() : false,
                jDat.contains("Stackable") ? jDat["Stackable"].toBool() : false);
    }
}
```

Each item class contains different constructors that are unique to it and I was trying to have this all be one line where I pull all the args from the JSON and loop through and essentially insert an array or list of arguments that will automatically call the right constructor (all sub-classes of the item class with different constructors). The number of arguments is unknown for each item, but are in order so that if I did pull them they would use the correct constructor. Is there something I'm missing, or is this the only way to achieve this?

This method will work just wondering if there is a more efficient way going forward, tried many different ways but this was the best i could find.

Comment: You could have the constructor for each type accept the json data directly and use that to initialize/assign its members. I realize this is an example but I doubt it compiles.

Comment: You cannot switch on string...

Comment: First thing I'd do is getting common fields out of the way. As presented, both types of items have `Name`, `Description`, `Rarity`, `Cursed` and `Stackable` - you can read these first and only pass them to correct constructor instead of repeating yourself over and over.

Comment: ThorsSerializer handles [polymorphic types](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer/blob/master/doc/example3.md) automatically. It uses a declarative nature and will create the appropriate types automatically with little (or no code from you).

Answer (score 1):

The common types are the parameter type `JsonObject` which is used to construct the base type `GameData`.

First, make sure that each class that derives from `GameData` has a constructor that accepts a `JsonObject` as parameter.

Still, that solves not the creation of such objects at runtime, therefore we need a mechanism, which returns a constructor function provided with an object type (e.g. `jDat["ItemType"]`).

For that you could introduce a map, which maps the types as string to a function object, e.g.

```
static std::map<std::string, GameDataCtor> game_data_map;
```

where `GameDataCtor` could be defined as

```
using GameDataCtor = std::function<GameData*(const JsonObject&)>;
```

Then, simply populate the map, like:

```
game_data_map["Weapon"] = [](const JsonObject& data){ return new weapon(data); };
```

and implement a function which returns a proper `GameData` object:

```
GameData* createGameData(const std::string& type, const JsonObject& data)
{
    //if (!game_data_map.contains(type)/*c++20*/) return nullptr;
    return game_data_map[type](data);
}
```